# Basic usage of keys - Extract single item prop from data list

Tags: reactjs, list, key

In React I have an array of projects (only 2 in this example). Each project has:

- key
- name
- info

I would like to be able to render, for example, only one project name. Everything I have tried gives me the whole list. I am confused on the format I need to use to:

1. Set up my ID
2. Tell React what specific ID I want to render

I have tried creating different formats (Try number 1 & 2) using .map

```
function ProjectList() {
  const projects = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Shop",
      date: "2019",
      info: "info of 1",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Hotel",
      date: "2019",
      info: "info of 2",
    },
  ]

  const findProjectInfo = projects.map (project =>(
    <div key={1}> 
      <h2 key={project.ID}>
        {project.info} 
      </h2>
    </div>
    ))

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='TRY NUMBER ONE' key={1}>
        {projects.map (project=> (
          <div key={project.ID}>
            <div> {project.name}</div>
            <div> {project.info}</div>
          </div> 
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className='TRY NUMBER TWO' key={1}>
        {findProjectInfo}
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjectList
```

Everything I tried gives me the two items of my list and not only the 1st one as I would want.

Comment: Why did you think map *would* return a shorter array than you started with? What are you trying to do with key= *outside* the loop?

Comment: Why ? By lack of knowledge and general understanding I would say :) I guess [key] wasnt the right way to tackle my problem, as Ricardo said below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are simply iterating through your array, that is why you are getting every element from array as result.

You need to first `filter` your array using provided ID and then you can iterate using `map`,

```
{projects
    .filter(projects => projects.id === providedID) //providedID can be stored in state
    .map(project => (
        <div key={project.id}>
           <h2 key={project.id}>{project.info}</h2>
        </div>
    ))
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-98sp9?fontsize=14)

**Note:** Don't use `key` like this,

```
<div className='TRY NUMBER ONE' key={1}>
```

Also make sure you don't repeat the `key` for multiple elements.

---

**Update**

Changing state and getting project details based on selected project ID.

[Demo1](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-nnbxq?fontsize=14)

Comment: First question posted on stackoverflow, multiples answers within 5min. Thank you very much. Problem solved now.

Comment: Ravibagul, would you mind explaining more in detail how you would change the useState from 0 to 1 and actually change or setup the ProvidedID? My final goal here would be to be able to select and display different parts of this list in others components.

Comment: @Raizorbak Updated my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

[.map will always return you an array with the same size as the original](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). What you want to do is find a specific element, like this:

```
const project1 = findProjectInfo.find(project => project.id === 1);
```

This will return a single object instead of an array, which you can then render:

```
<div>
  <div>{project.name}</div>
  <div>{project.info}</div>
</div>
```

[More info on Array.prototype.find() here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

The `key` prop is not to be used for anything related to this. It is a special prop that helps React know when components change, and only usually needed when you want to render arrays (like when you use `.map`), or in a few more advanced cases.

Comment: First question posted on stackoverflow, multiples answers within 5min. Thank you very much. Problem solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```js
const projects = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Shop",
      date: "2019",
      info: "info of 1",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Hotel",
      date: "2019",
      info: "info of 2",
    },
  ];

function ProjectList() {
  
  const [selectedProject,setSelectedProject] = React.useState(0);
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Select Project</div>
      <button onClick={()=>setSelectedProject(0)}>Project 1</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setSelectedProject(1)}>Project 2</button>
      <br/><br/>
      <div><b>Project name: </b>{projects[selectedProject].name}</div>
      <div><b>Project date: </b>{projects[selectedProject].date}</div>
      <div><b>Project info: </b>{projects[selectedProject].info}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(<ProjectList/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: First question posted on stackoverflow, multiples answers within 5min. Thank you very much. Problem solved now.

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark one as correct and upvote the ones that you found out to be helpful!